# How to make a curl request with API key?

Tags: php, curl, request, api-key

I have endpoint and apiKey from received documentation but I keep getting same error when I pass token:

> "{"message":"Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=Basic 123456789717896="}"

And my code:

```
    $endpoint = 'https://my.example.co.uk/full-example-new/prod';
    $apiKey = '123456789717896';

    $ch = curl_init();

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic';
    $headers[] = 'x-api-key: ' . $apiKey;
    $headers[] = 'Credential:' . '';
    $headers[] = 'Signature:' . '';
    $headers[] = 'SignedHeaders:' . '';
    $headers[] = 'X-Amz-Date' . date( 'Ymd\THis\Z');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    $body = '{}';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    $something = curl_exec($ch);

    return $something;
```

And in docs:

> You will need to add the following header to auth:

```
x-api-key: 123456789717896
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The Errormessage describes your problem perfectly. Add those headers.

Comment: I tried, but error message is the same. I don't have values for that credentials so I need to leave them empty.  I updated post. @DieterKräutl

Comment: time() = Timestamp not a date!

Comment: Has the error message changed?

Comment: No. Stil the same. @DieterKräutl

Comment: Well the headers are not right. Authorisation header has to have a Parameter called Credential usually a string like your api key (Its Base64 encoded username:password).
Authorization: Basic {Credentialstring}

Comment: To see what I mean:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization